# Configure Eleventy not to use directories for output?

Tags: eleventy

Is it possible somehow to do a general configuration for Eleventy so that 'my_file.html' in the input folder ends up just as 'my_file.html' in the _site folder, not '/my_file/index.html'?

I know I can do it on a file by file basis with permalinks. But I'd like it configured for the site as a whole, if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, since this behavior [isn't encouraged](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/permalinks/#cool-uris-dont-change), there isn't a simple configuration option to disable the directory output.

However, since `permalink` is part of the [data cascade](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-cascade/), you can set a global default, and in combination with the [`filePathStem` computed data](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-eleventy-supplied/#filepathstem), you can set the output to be `.html` files.

To set a `permalink` using a global data file, add a `permalink.js` file to your global `_data` directory.

```js
// _data/permalink.js
module.exports = '/{{ page.filePathStem }}.html'
```

There is also a config global data option [coming soon to v1.0.0](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-global-custom/). I am not sure if it will handle the `{{ page.filePathStep }}` preprocessing, but if it does, that could be an option too, especially since it will keep config-related things inside the config file.

Comment: Great answer!  Just a big warning that `permalink` strings will be processed to the syntax of the template file, so using a string globally might be a bit iffy. Should be safer to use a function instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can control where Eleventy writes things out by specifying a permalink value in the front matter. This is covered here: https://www.11ty.dev/docs/permalinks/#remapping-output-(permalink)

An example would be:

```
---
permalink: "/my_file.html"
---
```

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed where the OP said he wanted to configure it once.